# Scatter plot of correlated variables in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

i want do something like this:
[Example](http://www.google.pl/imgres?imgurl=http://mfiles.pl/pl/images/2/2c/Korelacja_Diagram.jpg&imgrefurl=http://mfiles.pl/pl/index.php/Punktowy_diagram_korelacji&h=281&w=472&sz=13&tbnid=QLlECiKPHwU4OM%3a&tbnh=67&tbnw=112&zoom=1&usg=__IiDqTIb6_9mUCd5LknVOQ8MvbwU=&docid=FbIPvZwL4MVnwM&sa=X&ei=P1WrUbWtAYm34AT8h4DgBA&ved=0CDoQ9QEwAg&dur=2396)

using r and ggplot2. My datase looks like that:
[dataset_image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/beztytuujcdj.png/)

How can i do it for any two varible from my dataset?

Comment: it should not be difficult to find examples of how to make a a simple scatterplot in R - if you're having trouble getting it to work then post your code

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html

Comment: just so you know: you're getting downvoted because this is a very, very basic question and you didn't suggest what effort you had put into solving the problem for yourself before asking for help here (e.g. googling "r scatterplot", which would have got you lots of useful information).  Another possibility is that you want something other than a simple scatterplot of two variables, and you've failed to ask your question very precisely ...

Answer (score 4):

A very basic `ggplot2` example:

```
a = runif(100)
b = runif(100)
df = data.frame(a, b)
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point()
```

For scatter plot matrices I'd have a look at [`plotmatrix`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/plotmatrix.html).